# CoreData Relationship and Show the list of image in Swiftui

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, nsset

I tried to store a list of images in CoreData, using relationship of entities.

The model are designed like this:
[image]
[image]

When add the data, I tried to code like this:

```
let imageData1 = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "Dummy1").jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
let imageData2 = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "Dummy2").jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
                
newItem.addToItemImages(NSSet(array: [imageData1!, imageData2!]))
                    
try? self.viewContext.save()
```

After that, I would like to retrieve them through SwiftUI, but I failed to do so:

```
    ForEach(Array(self.item.itemImages! as! Set), id:\.self) {image in
            Image(uiImage: image)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
        }
```

It complains unable to infer type of 'image' in the current context.

My question here:

1. what is the proper way to store sequence of images in CoreData. Is that my current approach fine? My current approach is 1 (item) to many (ItemImage) relationship. The ItemImage has a field named 'image' which is Binary Data type.
2. Is that my approach to store the ItemImage proper?
3. How can I get all the ItemImage (NSSet) from item, and then display using Image() of Swiftui?

Comment: Did you end up getting this figured out? Did you need to adjust @mmklug's answer to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Your entities seem to set up ok; I would only change the `Delete Rule` for the `itemImages` relationship in the `Item` entity to `Cascade` to avoid orphan ItemImages in the database.

To add images, you need to create instances of `ItemImage` first and then set the relationship to an `Item`. This could be done in one block as follows:

```
if let imageData = UIImage(named: "Dummy1")?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.85) {
    let image = ItemImage(context: moc)
    image.id = UUID()
    image.image = imageData
    image.ofItem = item
}
```

Your attempt of retrieving the images is not working because of two different reasons:

First: the compiler does not know that `item.itemImages` is a Set of `ItemImage`. The automatic generated code declares itemImages as

```
@NSManaged public var itemImages: NSSet?
```

So you need to provide this information in your code by casting to `Set<ItemImage>` instead of simply to `Set`. You could avoid this by changing the declaration of `itemImages` to:

```
@NSManaged public var itemImages: Set<ItemImage>?
```

Second: the elements of your set are of type `ItemImage` (and not `UIImage`), so in your code you need to call `Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: image.image!)!)` to create an `Image` (i.e creating an `UIImage` from the data contained in the `image` attribute of the `ItemImage` object). The updated code (keeping the many force unwraps I would personally not use in my own code) would look like this:

```
ForEach(Array(item.itemImages! as! Set<ItemImage>)) { image in
    Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: image.image!)!)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(maxWidth: 300, maxHeight: 300)
}
```

If you change the declaration of `itemImages` as described above this could be simplified to

```
ForEach(Array(item.itemImages!)) { image in
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must first make records of type `ItemImage`, and assign the image to the `image` attribute of each record. Then you can use the generated `addToItemImages` function to add these records to the `itemImages` relation of an `Item` record.